# POSIX equivalent of OpenBSD's find -false

Tags: find, posix, openbsd

[GNU find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html), [FreeBSD find](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) and [NetBSD find](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?find+1+NetBSD-current) all have option `-false`, but [OpenBSD find](https://man.openbsd.org/find.1) does not.

Granted, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) does *not* require an option `-false` for `find`, but still, this is very annoying.

How can I obtain the equivalent behavior of `-false` (ideally, in a fully POSIX-compatible way) for OpenBSD?

**Edit:** I'm looking for a *general* and ideally *mechanical* replacement, as in, is there a way to rewrite a command line written with `-false` into one without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options will in practice always evaluate to 'true':

```
-mindepth 0
-name '*'
-perm -0
```

Use `!` to invert the result and get a guaranteed 'false'.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that I wanted a *general* solution, in which case `-mindepth 0` (which is a global option and not in POSIX) would not be the best idea, but the others work just fine.